# SQL Query for multiple time frames

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull a report from a data set , the conditions are as follow:

Customer A,B and C produced 100, 150 and 200 tickets respectively in a year.

A's period from 1/1/2022 till 3/30/2022
B's period from 1/10/2022 till 6/20/2022
C's period from 6/10/2022 till 9/5/2022

I want to pull how many cases each customer produced while they are in the incubation period. Such that the report will not include any cases outside the customers incubation period.

The start date and end date in available in a table.

Hopefully I was able to explain this, thanks for your help.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: And we need to see some actual sample data and desired results.